# is there a way to show temporary unavailable page when Jenkins is building?

Tags: jenkins, grails, build, jenkins-plugins

When i am building the web application using jenkins, during the time it is building the production site will be down. Instead of no message at all is it possible to show a custom message such as "Will be back in less than 5 minutes". I appreciate any guide. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would be better to use a [blue-green deployment approach with Jenkins](https://medium.com/arabamlabs/blue-green-deployment-with-jenkins-98393bba2327) instead of having your grails site down during the build.

That way, you have two identical environments configured exactly the same way. While one environment is active and serving end users, the other environment remains idle.

You deploy to the blue environment and test there.
Then you switch, deploy on the green one and go live. The downtime is then minimal.

See [`grails-samples/grails-website`](https://github.com/grails-samples/grails-website) as an example.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but at this point our only option is 1 server 1 app. so i appreciate answer to the original question.